# Directed cycle space

Tags: graph-theory

I understand the idea and basic rules of a cycle space of an undirected simple graph. It is possible to extend the way one can express any cycle as a Delta (symmetric difference) "sum" of fundamental cycles to directed graphs. This is done by giving fundamental cycles consistent orientation (specified by their co-tree link) and summarize this information in a circulation matrix C (why is this matrix totally unimodular is my secondary question). It is then possible to express any given (consistently oriented) directed cycle as a similar "sum" of those fundamental cycles who share their co-tree link with the given cycle, where this time "sum" means addition/subtraction (depending on whether the co-tree link's direction agrees/or not with the given cycle's orientation) of the corresponding rows of C.
What puzzles me is this: as we keep on adding/subtracting these rows of C, we may (and usually do) get components outside the -1 to 1 range, but in the end of the process (completing the cycle), this becomes impossible (the components are automatically in the -1 to 1 range).  WHY (must all the other integers disappear)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is parallel to the undirected situation.

By adding/subtracting (oriented) fundamental cycles which share a co-tree link with the given (oriented) cycle always results in a collection of directed edges with the following two properties:

(i) each edge acquires a (positive) integer multiplicity (when this multiplicity becomes $0$, the edge is deleted),

(ii) the net degree (added for all - accounting for their multiplicity - "in" edges, subtracted for "out" edges) must stay equal to $0$ for all vertices.

The result is then subtracted from the original cycle; the involved co-tree links must thus disappear since they appear exactly once (due to their uniqueness - each appeared in exactly one term of the result, and thus the answer), and with the same direction, both in the result and in the original cycle. What is left is then a subset of the corresponding spanning tree (with potentially multiple edges, and also with at least two leaves - vertices with only one neighbor). But this "leftover" is also required to have all vertices of zero degree; to meet both of these conditions is possible only when all of its edges disappear (their resulting multiplicity is always zero). This proves that the result is identical to the original graph.

A very simple extension of this argument enables us to prove that it is possible to add/subtract the individual rows of any collection of rows of C to get the directed analog of their Delta (i.e. $\mod 2$) sum. This is sufficient to prove the total unimodularity of C.